# Why are some questions closed and why are some deleted instead of closed?

Tags: discussion

Is there a consistent standard, or do people apply their own standards?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/faq#close and http://stackoverflow.com/faq#deletion

Comment: For the record, it can't be deleted "instead" of closed - it must be closed first before it can be deleted. (Unless deleted directly by moderator, but it's very rare)

Answer (score 5):

I like the explanation [given recently at Programmers Meta](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2964/why-are-closed-questions-not-being-deleted):

> There are many reasons why closed questions aren't deleted.
>
> 1. We have to give time for the OP (and others) to improve the question so it can be reopened.
> 2. The closure may have been incorrect in the first place. Having the question visible means it can be reopened if necessary.
> 3. It takes time to work through all the closed questions, working out which are salvageable and which need to be deleted.
> 4. People complain bitterly if highly upvoted closed questions are deleted.
>
> ...
>
> Ultimately these questions will be deleted.