# How do deletion policies surrounding deleted questions change when questions are deleted due to being possible duplicates?

Tags: feature-request

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Should be [Closed as duplicate] questions redirect to what they are duplicate of?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/104284/should-be-closed-as-duplicate-questions-redirect-to-what-they-are-duplicate-of)

The thing with possible duplicate questions is that the "search as you type" feature works better when you have some duplicate questions posed in a different way (otherwise, people will end up asking them again). At least that's how it's done on Quora (the old question just automatically redirects to the new question with a question alias).

This is a follow-up question to [Why are some questions closed and why are some deleted instead of closed?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/121040/why-are-some-questions-closed-and-why-are-some-deleted-instead-of-closed)

Comment: Ahem, who says they are deleted? Dupes are usually merged, not deleted... And in the rare occasion of a dupe getting deleted, it's usually for very good reasons.

Comment: @Yannis merged? Nah. I don't think there is much merging going on. They're just left whether they are, arent't they?

Comment: Oh, in the thread I linked, gnat said "Ultimately these questions will be deleted." at the end of his quote. So that was what got me worried.

Comment: @InquilineKea That doesn't apply to duplicate questions. Duplicates are almost always left in place or merged.

Comment: @Pekka Depends on the site I guess... In any case, dupes are more likely to be merged than deleted.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Should be \[Closed as duplicate\] questions redirect to what they are duplicate of?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/104284/should-be-closed-as-duplicate-questions-redirect-to-what-they-are-duplicate-of), [Automatically redirect anonymous user from unanswered duplicate question to corresponding answered version](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125220/automatically-redirect-anonymous-user-from-unanswered-duplicate-question-to-corr)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's some confusion in the comments, so let me outline what should be happening as I understand the network policies:

- All other closed questions are generally deleted (or locked for historical purposes), but dupes are an exception (see next point).
- Duplicates are never deleted unless the deletion reason is unrelated to it being a duplicate.  (For example, being extremely off-topic and not up for migration. The parent duplicate should be deleted as well in that case.)  Basically, if it *wasn't* a dupe, would it still be closed and deleted?  If yes, then it should be deleted.
- Duplicates are merged only if they're **exact** duplicates **and** both garnered useful, but different, answers.  In other words, the same person posted the same question twice and both got answers before the duplication was noticed.

Comment: Thanks - this was the precise answer I was looking for (sorry for the confusing original question). I've just changed the title of the original question as such.